# Duke fishron help!

Tags: terraria-console

Each time I use ironskin,wrath,regen,endurance,thorns,magic power and mana regen for mage,wings,frostspark boots,cross necklass,destroyer emblem,and ankh shield/paladin shield,though for mage I replace the emblem with a mana flower. also this is 3ds,so sadly,no daedalus stoembow or influx waver. Okay so using my newly aquired vampire knives I can get to half health,but the get destroyed by the cthulhunados. So now,I just need to focus on that second phase strategy. Still using same potions,but added rage. Thinking about inferno for the sharks. Also,I use beetle shell armor.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind,I managed to beat him with spectre regen and razorpine.